# Uploading an Asset from a custom CP-Tab in Craft 2.x

Tags: plugin-development, templating, assets, assetfilemodel

I have been looking through answers here at stackexchange but somehow can't figure out what i am missing. I simply want to upload an asset to a specific asset folder in my plugin.

<s>I do get an error: `Call to a member function getTempName() on null`</s>

Thanks a lot, much appreciated

<s>this is my form:</s>

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="assetLinks/upload/UploadFile">
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}
  <input type="file" name="file[]">
  <button type="submit">Upload file</button>
</form>
```

this is my controller:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class AssetLinks_UploadController extends BaseController
{

    public function actionUploadFile()
    {
        // Get info about the uploaded file
        $file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('fileInputName');
        $tempFilePath = $file->getTempName();

        // Find the target folder
        $folder = craft()->assets->findFolder(array(
            'sourceId' => 1,
            'path' => 'uploads/documents/',
        ));

        // Turn the file into a managed asset within that folder
        craft()->assets->insertFileByLocalPath(
            $file->getTempName(),
            $file->getName(),
            $folder->id,
            AssetConflictResolution::KeepBoth
        );
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I have been reading through the docs and some other examples and decided to go for an AJAX File upload, which of course lead to new problems :-)

this is the controller:

```
    <?php
namespace Craft;

class AssetLinks_UploadController extends BaseController
{

  protected $valid_extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf');
  protected $assetSourceId = 1;
  public function actionUploadFile()
  {
      $this->requireAjaxRequest();
      $errors = array();
      $success = array();
      foreach ($_FILES['files']['error'] as $key => $error)
      {
          if (!$error)
          {
              $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
              $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
              $filenamePieces = explode('.', $filename);
              $extension = end($filenamePieces);
              if (!in_array($extension, $this->valid_extensions))
              {
                  $errors[] = "$filename has an invalid extension.";
                  continue;
              }

              $uploadDir = craft()->assetSources->getSourceById($this->uploadAssetSourceId)->settings['path'];
              $uploadDir = str_replace('{basePath}', craft()->config->get('environmentVariables')['basePath'], $uploadDir);
              if (move_uploaded_file($file, $uploadDir . $filename))
              {
                  IOHelper::deleteFile($file);
                  $file = $uploadDir . $filename;
                  $fileModel = new AssetFileModel();
                  $fileModel->sourceId = $this->assetSourceId;
                  $fileModel->folderId = $this->assetFolderId;
                  $fileModel->filename = IOHelper::getFileName($filename);
                  $fileModel->kind = IOHelper::getFileKind(IOHelper::getExtension($filename));
                  $fileModel->size = filesize($file);
                  $fileModel->dateModified = IOHelper::getLastTimeModified($file);
                  craft()->assets->storeFile($fileModel);
                  $success[] = "$filename was saved.";
              }
              else
              {
                  $errors[] = "$filename was unable to be saved.";
                  continue;
              }
          }
      }
      $this->returnJSON(compact('errors', 'success'));
  }
}
```

and this is the form and Ajax post:

```
{% extends "_layouts/cp" %}
{% set title = 'Asset Links' %}

{% set content %}


  <form class="upload"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input  type="hidden" name="action" value="assetLinks/upload/UploadFile">
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}
    <input class="file btn" type="file" name="file">
    <button data-icon="upload" class="uploadfile btn submit" type="submit">Upload file</button>
  </form>
  <div style="margin-top:20px" id="output" />


{% endset %}


{% set js %}
    $(function() {
      $("form").submit(function() {
        var url = '/actions/assetLinks/upload',
          files = $(this).find("[name=file]")[0].files,
          formdata = new FormData(),
          file,
          reader;

        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          file = files[i];
          if (window.FileReader) {
            reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          }
          formdata.append("files[]", file);
        }

        $("#output").html("Uploading...");

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
          contentType: false,
        success: function(json) {
          window.json = json;
          console.log(json);

          var errors = json['errors'],
              success = json['success'],
              html = "<p><b>" + errors.length + " errors, " + success.length + " successfully uploaded</b></p>";

              $("#output").html(html);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          alert("ERROR: " + xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
        }
      });

        return false;
      });
    })
{% endset %}
{% includeJs js %}
```

in wich i run into a 404, 
`http://test.test/actions/assetLinks/upload 404 (Not Found)`

it seems like i am addressing the wrong controller url ?

Comment: Are you using the correct field name for $file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('fileInputName')?

Comment: I am not sure to be honest, i posted all the data that is used in the plugin so its basically just the form and the uploadController

Comment: @AndrisSevcenko you were right was blind, i changed the input name to:file and  $file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('file');. it doesn't throw an error but doesn't upload anything

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just do as described in the craft docs?  -> https://craftcms.com/docs/assets-fields#uploading-files-from-front-end-entry-forms

Comment: I am using the same form, but i am using a custom controller that throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

use $allowAnonymous feature in your controller to allow your function to work if you are not logged in when uploading[just assuming you are trying to upload this as logged off user.]

Comment: thanks for the answer, its a cp-tab and only used when someone is logged in into the backend, i must have made a mistake somewhere else